# Laravel 5 clean install error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make working Laravel 5. I installed laravel and put it into this directory structure:

```
- www 
- - domains
- - - laravel.kozusnikjan.com (here is stored laravel installation)
```

When I tried to go to the url:
laravel.kozusnikjan.com, it returns:

Some warnings

> Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons

and this error:

> **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

Do you have please any idea, how to repair it?

Comment: If `putenv()` has been disabled - then you need to talk to your server host

Comment: putenv I think, it's  ok. It's just warning. And I know, I'm solving it. Do you think, the problem is caused by putnev?

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration of php.ini, search and erase "putenv", if found in inside the function "disable_functions="